# Allow client to view and download their images from national studio database by entering job number

Tags: php, html

I'm very new to PHP (as in starting today) having been thrown into the deep end, and this particular project has a deadline of 1 week today. I'm sat here scratching my head with no idea where to start. HTML and CSS isn't a problem however.

I work for a national photography studio chain. All images from each sitting and from each studio ends up on our internal server at our HQ. The folder structure is simple, with Studio Name folder -> Client Job Number -> Image JPG's. Each job number is unique to the client and they will also supply an email address which is referenced via a csv file.

I have to build a simple page with two form fields. The customer fills these in with their job number and their email address. Once submitted, their images are fetched from our server and displayed on the page. They can then download their images.

What is the bets way of achieving this and where do I start? I have searched for anything similar, but I can't seem to find anything that works in this way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the form is submitted. Read all files from the folder in to an array

```
$client_job_number = $_REQUEST['client_job_number'];
$dir = 'studio_folder/'.$client_job_number;
$files = scandir($dir);
```

Now display all image files

```
foreach($files as $file){

   if($file == '.' OR $file == '..'){
        continue;
    }
    else{
      echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$dir.'/'.$file.'"><img src = "'.$dir.'/'.$file.'"/></a>';
    }


 }
```

Comment: That will at least get me started, thanks very much!